Roslyn and .net5
I try to use the Roslyn-compiler to compile some sourcecode at runtime. To do so I did
public static void compile()
{
    SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(code);
}

Of course this code does not do much but it shows by problem:
Whenever I try to execute the compile-Method I get an Exception
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Maybe this is a version issue? I'm really stuck here.
I'm using VS2019 and .Net5 (I think this is the latest .Net VS2019 supports)
Via NuGetPackage Manager I included in my project:

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common V4.9.2
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp V4.9.2

Projectfile look like this
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="4.9.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.9.2" />
</ItemGroup>

When building I get warnings:
1>C:\Users\werber\.nuget\packages\system.text.encoding.codepages\8.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.targets(4,5): warning : System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 8.0.0 doesn't support net5.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net6.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk.
1>C:\Users\werber\.nuget\packages\system.collections.immutable\8.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\System.Collections.Immutable.targets(4,5): warning : System.Collections.Immutable 8.0.0 doesn't support net5.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net6.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk.
1>C:\Users\werber\.nuget\packages\system.reflection.metadata\8.0.0\buildTransitive\netcoreapp2.0\System.Reflection.Metadata.targets(4,5): warning : System.Reflection.Metadata 8.0.0 doesn't support net5.0 and has not been tested with it. Consider upgrading your TargetFramework to net6.0 or later. You may also set <SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings>true</SuppressTfmSupportBuildWarnings> in the project file to ignore this warning and attempt to run in this unsupported configuration at your own risk.

What to do and how to fix this?

You need to target packages that support the now out support .NET 5.

so am I just using the wrong versions of the right packages or the wrong packages at all? Are Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common/CSharp valid for .net5?

The error message is self-explanatory. Have you tried creating a project for that code and compiling it? Is this an error in the code that you're compiling or an error in the code that is compiling the code?

What error-message? I get build-Warnings about packages I never installed on purpose. Steps are: I had a .net5-Projekt which built and ran just fine. Now I wanted to use Roslyn to compile some code from inside my code. To do so I wrote the comile-method above and added the nuget-packages mentioned via pacjage-manager. How I can build and debug my program until the call to compile. When I want to step in that method, I get the exception "Could not load file or assembly". The compile-Method is not entered

Roslyn 4.x is only supported in Visual Studio 2022. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/roslyn-version-support?view=vs-2022 for the mapping between VS and Roslyn packages
